# Is it possible to charge a PSP with a 7.4 volt power supply?

Tags: psp

Would it damage my PSP (I think it's a second gen) if I plug it into a 7.4 volt power supply, or should I get a 5v regulator?

I would like to use 2 IMR cells when I'm on the road.

EDIT: Another way to think of this question is - does the PSP have an internal voltage regulator for charging, or do I need to give it a clean 5 volts?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the manual for the PSP models E1002 and E1003 and it clearly states that 5 volts is required input voltage. I would highly doubt that it has an internal voltage regulator if it comes with an external AC adapter.

I worked in a large electronics store in the UK and we occasionally got people who tried to blame us for using too high a voltage setting on the universal laptop power supply we sold them. The result was that it damaged their laptop, I suspect that doing this would have the same results as 7.4 volts is almost 50% higher than correct input voltage.

Comment: In the question I said that the voltage was coming from two IMR (LiMg) cells (batteries), each of which has a voltage of 3.7volts. I litterally just have two lithium cells in a battery holder, it would be nice to just use them for my PSP, but I can get a little 5v linear regulator for it tomorrow - if the 7.4volts would damage my PSP.  Sorry if the term "power supply" made it seem like a wall wart.  I was really referring to any sort of EMF.

Comment: ah sorry I have never heard that term for batteries in a holder before, I googled IMR and found no common definition so assumed it was some sort of general charger. What is the model number of your PSP? I will re-word my answer to better suit your question.